# Parse and Onesignal push notifications not working together - Android

Tags: parse-platform, onesignal, parse-android-sdk

Usually Parse notifications are received and it works well on my test android app.

when i added [Onesignal](https://onesignal.com/) to my project, Parse notification are not received anymore ?

What can be a possible conflict ?

Answer (score 1):

By default Parse uses it own "Google Project number" (Sender ID). For OneSignal you setup your own however if you have 2 different project numbers in your app the previously registered one will become unsubscribed.

If you're migrating over to OneSignal from Parse you should follow the blog post below to keep your channels.
https://onesignal.com/blog/important-note-for-android-parse-push-users/

Comment: usually cant we use more than GCM sender ID in the same project ?

Comment: Yes, add it to Parse by setting your Google Project number to `GCMSenderId` noted in the instructions above. Then when most of your users have switched over remove Parse or at least the notification part of it and add the OneSignal SDK to your app.

Comment: @jkasten I'm in the process of adding my own sender ID to Parse but I have a huge problem. When I send a push notification from Parse, the installation entry in _Installation gets deleted, although the notification is received.
I followed the steps in the link, and I believe the issue is because of the fact that, Parse sees that GCMSenderId is set, it sends the push using my own sender ID and API key I put in settings, but somehow it also sees that the deviceToken is incompatible with Parse's sender ID, to it deletes the installation entry. This seems like a really bad bug? Did you fix this?